# Is this slime mold and if so, what should we do about it?

Tags: identification, diseases

This started popping up on the surface of the soil in our garden...in quite a few spots. Very mucus-like, quite firm. Very weird and disturbing. Have never seen it before. It is even in a large pot. Please help identify and let us know what to do...Thanks.[image]

Comment: take a photo a day later, that will show what it is.